# Encode HTML Entities inside an Element Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following HTML, how would I go about encoding the HTML entities inside the `<pre><code class="language-html"></code></pre>` block?  n.b., on the actual page where this will be used there are *many* such blocks.

```
<div><strong>Rendered</strong>
    <div>This is a div, which contains a <p>p</p> and a <span>span</span>.</div>
</div>

<div><strong>Code</strong>
    <pre><code class="language-html">
        <div>This is a div, which contains a <p>p</p> and a <span>span</span>.</div>
    </code></pre>
</div>
```

The goal is to have this output the following:

This is a div, which contains a
p
and a span.

`<div>This is a div, which contains a <p>p</p> and a <span>span</span>.</div>`

(i.e., the first copy of the code should render, while the second should merely *display*.)

**Edit** *(14 Feb 2016)*: 
[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery) addresses a slightly different issue and, consequently, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML-encoding in JavaScript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to grab the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html), then set it as the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text):

```js
$('pre > code.language-html').text(function() {
 $(this).text($(this).html());
})

// or simpler
//$('pre > code.language-html').text(function() { return $(this).html(); })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>This is a div, which contains a <p>p</p> and a <span>span</span>.</div>

<div><pre><code class="language-html">
    <div>This is a div, which contains a <p>p</p> and a <span>span</span>.</div>
</code></pre></div>

<div><pre><code class="language-html">
    <div>This is a div, which contains a <p>p</p> and a <span>span</span>.</div>
</code></pre></div>
```

Comment: It may be simple, but it works for what I'm doing.  Thanks.